# How to animate something to a fixed pixel value? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to do the following

```
$("#nurseView").animate({"left": "+=100px"}, "slow");
```

But what if I want to animate something to exactly 1576px (X value) No matter of the current pixel value? The above only tells you to move +100px in the right direction and not move to a specific X pixel value.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use that method like this:

> `$("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1576px"}, "slow");`

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$("#nurseView").animate({left: 1576}, "slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) actually doesn't make it as obvious it could.
But it's still pretty plain to see.

```
$("#nurseView").animate({"left": "1576px"}, "slow");
```